# Printing menu freezes on kde apps since upgrade 17.04 -> 17.10

Tags: printing, kde, 17.10

The current behaviour is as follows, both for `Okular` and for `kile`

```
$ okular --version
okular 1.1.3
$ kile --version
Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.34
Kile: 2.1.3
```

- the programs behave normally on browsing pdf / editing tex files
- it pauses when pressing the print button for 90+sec without terminal output, the print menu then opens.
- I can then choose the printer and the print options, all printers show up normally, but choosing one results again in 45+sec freeze
- pressing print then results in another 90+sec freeze, before the print is released **to the standard printer** even if I chose a different printer in the menu

Side infos:

- There is no weird cpu or memory usage during the freeze.
- Printing menu and printing with `evince` works totally normal.
- I don't know if this is related, but I can also not cancel or move print jobs from the Ubuntu 17.10 settings gui, while it works fine using the cups interface http://localhost:631/jobs/.

Any help with debugging appreciated!

Comment: Is it only in Okular?

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks for the question, just tried ``kile`` and it also freezes (not since 3+ minutes). I will update the question if I find out how kile behaves.

Comment: It's software troubleshooting 101. If the problem occurs with several programs it has nothing to do with the programs themselves, in which case mentioning one misleads anyone trying to help. Same as saying "I can't open website X" and at the end the user has no internet connection.